# enLaptop Overheating after installing win 8.1

Tags: laptop, drivers, graphics-card, windows-8.1

I recently updated my laptop to Windows 8.1. Laptop overheats when I play HD videos and also while playing games.Sometimes it shuts down on its own.

This wasn't the case when I was using Windows 8. May be there's an issue with the graphics drivers. I have updated all drivers provided by Dell.

Config:

- Dell Inspiron 15R SE 7520
- Intel i7 3612QM 2.1GHz
- AMD Radeon HD 7730M + INTEL HD 4000 (switchable)
- 8 gb RAM.

Also, when i disable intel graphics, i get an error saying no amd drivers are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give the laptop a good dusting and have the latest BIOS installed as they often contain fan speed adjustments to fix overheating issues. Also there's usually settings in the BIOS to adjust fan speed that may help.

Comment: can you tell me what to do exactly? i have installed the latest bios. how do i manually adjust the fan speed?